# How to start KDE from command line interface

Tags: fedora, xorg, kde, desktop-environment, display-manager

I installed Fedora 38 via the Network Installer (also called Everything) and there was no desktop environment preinstalled so I installed `plasma-desktop` package which is labelled as **[Plasma Desktop shell](https://packages.fedoraproject.org/pkgs/plasma-desktop/plasma-desktop/)**.

However, I have no idea what to do next to start the desktop environment. I don't know much about desktop environment but I frequently saw **display manager** (e.g., SDDM) and **graphical session** (e.g., Xorg) while googling for a solution.

#### Update

The issue is resolved after installing `sddm` package since the `plasma-desktop` package doesn't come with a display manager.

Comment: Try: `sudo systemctl set-default graphical.target` and reboot

Comment: Instead of rebooting I think you can start the display manager service: `sudo systemctl start display-manager.service` (but run the previous systemd command `... set-default ...` ) in order to have the GUI session enabled and runs on next boot.

Comment: Have you tried a simple `startx` ?